# take char input and store it in an array

Tags: c, string, input, char

I want to take n number of inputs and save it in the arrays c[] and p[] and later use them...

I have currently written this,but i'm not getting desired output

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
int main()
{
    int n,t,i,j,size=0;
    char s[100000];
    char c[100];
    char p[100];
    scanf("%d", &n);

    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        scanf("%c", &c[i]);
        scanf("%c", &p[i]);
    }

    for(i=0; i<n;i++)
    {
        printf("%c %c", c[i],p[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `it doesn't work` - can you show expected output when it will `work`?

Comment: i want it to be like
4
w r
2 9
f g
q t
now c should store w2fq and p should store r9gt

Answer (score 3):

Considering from your second comment: "i want it to be like 4 w r 2 9 f g q t now c should store w2fq and p should store r9gt ",
you should change all the `for(...)` loop with `for(i=0;i<n/2;i++)`

Answer (score 1):

Use this

```
for(i=0; i<n;i++)
{
    scanf("%c %c", &c[i], &p[i]);
}
```

`%s` is for string of characters.
If you want to read only one character, you should use `%c`.

Comment: program crashed by doing so

Answer (score 0):

```
for(i=0;i<n;i++)
{
    scanf(" %c", &c[i]);//skip space character
    scanf(" %c", &p[i]);
}
```